# how to properly query in collections page in shopify liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have create many collections like **All Products**, **New Releases**, **T-Shirts**, **Pants** etc. And I have two categories of products like **Men's** and **Women's**. Some collections specifically for **Men's** and some collections specifically for **Women's**. I create two tags **Men's** and **Women's**. I create `menu` by `collections` query by `tags`. My my products collection `url` is like this:

```
/collections/all-products/mens
/collections/all-products/womens
/collections/new-releases/mens
/collections/new-releases/womens
/collections/bras/womens
```

I want to show some text and menu list when `collection.url` show `/mens` or `/womens`.

```
{% if collection.url contains mens %}
    do something
{% endif %
```

Above condition not working. I know why not working because `{{ collection.url }}` provide `/collections/all-products`. `{{ page.url }}` will not work for collection `object`. I haven't find any suggestion or liquid code reference where show men's or women's products in collections page it will show specific text.

If use in `loop` it will work.

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
        {% if tag contains 'mens' %}
            <h3>Mens Products</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Above code will not work for me because it's inside `loop`. I need to show outside of `loop`. I don't understand how to achieve it. here is the [reference site](https://www.gymshark.com/collections/all-products/mens). Below have image how I want.

[image]

> Need help!

Comment: man = singular
men = plural
mens... doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the `current_tags`, refer to docs: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/current-tags

This will return an array of all the tags you are viewing at the moment (in case you are viewing more than one tag).

So your check will be:

```
{% if current_tags contains 'mens' %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

That's pretty much the just of it.

Comment: Thanks for your ans. I checked many times above reference before asking the question but not working. I figure this out. `{% for tag in collection.all_tags %}{% if current_tags contains tags %}{% if tag == 'mens' %}` Do something `{% endif %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}`. It's working for me. Is I'm wrong?

Comment: @Rahul you are doing the same thing as me, but you are inserting it in a loop, if your solution work, there is no reason why the the provided one does not work. The only why it's not working if your tag is not called `mens` but something else.

Answer (score 0):

I really like how the menu is coming along! Here are some ideas you could consider for your category specific menu, if you've not gotten where you want yet.

1. For your url strategy, what you're looking for is **handle**. Handles are specific to liquid.  https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/basics/handle
2. You could make a custom collection template if those 2 categories need to be fairly different: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-create-alternate-templates. If you do that, then you can use `template_prefix` from the collection object.
3. Assign a variable outside your loop and then set it inside the loop like:

   `{% assign is_mens = false %}
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
      {% if tag contains 'mens' %}
        {% assign is_mens = true %} 
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`

then {% if is_mens %} or {% unless is_mens %} for your dynamic content, or a case statement to define content specific to categories in your menu.

Hope this helps!